# Wrong \overbrace with Minion Math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math

Using `\overbrace` with Minion Math yields the brace being printed over the equation. Latin Modern and TeX Gyre Pagella works fine, so it seems a font specific problem.

[image]

This happens in inline and display math; both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. `\underbrace` seems to work fine. Could be that the `MATH` table is incorrect? Can it be fixed somehow with `XeLaTex`? (For some other reason I can't use `LuaLaTeX`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\(\vec{e}_{i}=(\overbrace{0,\ldots,0,\underset{i}{1},0,\ldots,0}^{n})\),
$i=1,2,\dots,n$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand. I was just curious is someone has already tackle this problem. I would try your workaround

Comment: @HenriMenke I am using a properly licenced Minion Math (version 1.024. Which version of the font do you have?

Comment: Very sorry, I apologize for the false accusation. I'm using version 1.026 of MinionMath.  I remember that I also had problem with 1.024 but after emailing Johannes Küster with my license number and a description of the problem I received the corrected 1.026 files.

Comment: BTW, you can check whether the MATH table is there using `otfinfo -t <file>`.